# same max record in code

Tags: c#, linq

my application is used on many PC calling same database on the server
the application is creating new object of the table to insert,
one field is primary, two other fields are integers.
my code logic is getting the max() of those fields and increment them in the code

```
int x = 1;
var maxx = jde.Work_Order_Completion_Header_Tables.Max(c => c.UniqueKeyId);
                            if (maxx != null)
                            {
                                x = (int)maxx + 1;
                            }
```

but when the application is running on more than one PC am getting duplicat
record

```
ID  UniqueKeyID  UniqueKeyIDCompletion
 1     1002              2002
 2     1003              2003
 3     1003              2003
```

Comment: you should enable auto-increment on the columns in DB side

Comment: but  auto-increment can be set only for one field which the ID coz it is the Primary key

Comment: it is not mandatory

Comment: What database are you using?